# unable to differentiate future.get() timeoutexception and sqltimeoutexception

Tags: java, spring, exception

Im using method which returns Future> ie

```
Future<List<Map<String, Object>> getdetails();
```

inside this function using spring AsyncResult to query results from postgresstable.

The above method is inside a rest service.

So the issue is when the Database is timedout , when future.get() is called im getting exception as TimeoutException ,but would like to see specific exception as SqlTimeoutexception but this always throws TimeoutException instead of SQLTimeout.

This is required as i want developer know ie the service timeout or Sqltimeout specifically.

Comment: Is your SQL timeout longer or shorter than the timeout defined in your executor service?

Comment: SQL timeout is shorter

Comment: When you call `Future.get()`, catch the `TimeoutException` and throw its cause.

Comment: cause gives just timeout but not sqltimeout exception,how to differentiate whether its Db timeout or service timeout???

Comment: Can someone please help!!